# CXF always return url in WSDL with whom it was open for the first time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap, wsdl, cxf

I create `SOAP` endpoint with `CXF`:

```
@Bean
Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, myEndpoint);
    endpoint.publish(path);
    return endpoint;
}
```

And when I open url in my browser like: `http://localhost:6666/app/ws?wsdl`
I have this URL in returned wsdl:  `<soap:address location="http://localhost:6666/app/ws"/>`

But when I open with external URL: `http://172.16.105.134:6666/app/ws?wsdl`
does not matter I have this URL in returned wsdl:  `<soap:address location="http://localhost:6666/app/ws"/>`

**In general, I always get the url that I first open.**

But my task is always to return the url from which it was requested. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL is cached by `org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl`. You can provide your own implementation of `org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager` or use the `publishedEndpointUrl` property to have it update (see https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/rt/frontend/jaxws/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxws/EndpointImpl.java#L347).